# PHP: search from mysqli

Tags: php, search, mysqli

I have a search.php  page with this code

```
<html>
<body style="background-color: azure">
    please import your search request:
    <br>
    <form method="get" action="searchprocess.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="please import here" name="search">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the searchprocess.php is below

```
<?php
require_once 'functions.php';
$search=$_GET['search'];
$search = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]i#","", $search);

$query="Select * from names where firstname LIKE '%$search%'";

$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$count =mysqli_num_rows($result);
var_dump($result);
if ( $count == 0)
{
    $output = "there is noting to show you ... sorry search another thing <a href='search.php'>back to search page</a>";
    echo $output;
}

else{
    echo "<table>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $id = $result['id']; 
        $firstname = $result['firstname'];
        $lastname = $result['lastname'];
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$id.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$firstname.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$lastname.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';


    }
     echo "</table>";

}

?>
```

I have wamp and problem is when try my code it's error on line on the line below

```
$id=$row['id'];
```

Comment: What is the error? Check out ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question. It'll help everyone out.

Comment: This is a simple typo problem.

Answer (score 0):

Youuse the wrong var.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $id = $result['id'];
  $firstname = $result['firstname'];
  $lastname = $result['lastname'];
```

Should be:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $id = $row['id'];
  $firstname = $row['firstname'];
  $lastname = $row['lastname'];
```

I encourage you to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to avoid SQL injection attacks.